# Resizing images into LinearLayout and HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout, horizontalscrollview

how can i set the images which are in the HorizontalScrollView

As you can see the images are so much wide, i need them to be of normal size.

This is my code for the `HorizontalScrollView` xml file:

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/hscrollview"
    android:layout_weight="0.2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

This is what i have tried programmatically.

```
    private ImageView getImageView(final Integer image, final int index) {

    imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);

    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(index);

        }
    });

   imageView.setImageResource(image);

    return imageView;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

to

```
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.

it worked but i faced with a new problem. images too far between itself.

this is a link that u can look at : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7DsX9upspr7RlhFazVpZlU0Tlk/view